# How to specify custom binary name in Soong?

Tags: android-source, android-soong

I'm building custom C++ binary to add to AOSP build and I need to use new Soong build (.bp) files (which is Bazel-based, I learned). By default, "name" of the module will become binary name, but i need to change it. Is there any way to do it?

So in the example below I would like the generated binary be "myzip"

```
cc_binary {
    name: "gzip",
    srcs: ["src/test/minigzip.c"],
    shared_libs: ["libz"],
    stl: "none",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `stem` property for this, for example:

```
cc_binary {
    name: "gzip",
    srcs: ["src/test/minigzip.c"],
    shared_libs: ["libz"],
    stl: "none",
    multilib: {
        lib32: {
            stem: "gzip",
        },
        lib64: {
            stem: "gzip64",
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Is that an official feature? Just failed to find official docs. Can I use stem on the same level as name and other properties? I do not need variants, just hard-coded custom name.

Comment: Of course official, you can find it here https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6186764/linux/latest/view/soong_build.html for ```cc_binary```. Yes,  use it on the same level like ```name``` property.

Comment: Thanks this works generally (sadly it does not in my case 'cause I need to use it in combination with overrides: so both stem and override cause compilation error :/)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is right, `stem` is the option used to rename the output. In its simplest form, `stem` option could be used as below for this specific scenario:

```
cc_binary {
    name: "gzip",
    stem: "myzip",
    srcs: ["src/test/minigzip.c"],
    shared_libs: ["libz"],
    stl: "none",
}
```